# Using multiple threads inside java swingworker background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I am running jobs as background process using java swingworker

```
protected static class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
    //while (!isCancelled()) {
    Build_JobParams.runJob();
    //}
    return null;
}
```

Now, I need to call multiple times (asynchronously) the background process using different parameters. As it is background process, 2nd call is overriding the first call parameters. One way I tried is using multiple threads like Thread t1 = new Thread(){ ... but it is throwing exceptions intermittently.

Any better suggestions. Note, I can't wait in the done() { .. method to invoke the 2nd call as I have making many calls and not sure of the number of calls initially. Please suggest if there is some good way.

Comment: ExecutorService is better for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ExecutorService with a fixed size thread pool. You can find more information on how to set the correct pool size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128436/setting-ideal-size-of-thread-pool)

Here is what can try:

1. Create an executor service:

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) // setting arbitrary value to 5

2. Create a callable by implementing Callable interface
3. Call Build_JobParams.runJob() in call method.
4. service.submit(/** submit instance of "Callable" here **/)

If Build_JobParams.runJob() is not returning any value you can also call 
service.execute but in that case you need to create a Runnable.

Hope this helps!!